# Wrapping $.ajax with Promise doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

What I've been trying is to call `$.ajax` multiple times, until the result is empty.

Here is a simplified version of my experimentation...

```
        var objects = [];

        function getObjects (page){
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            $.ajax({
              url : url+"&pageNumber="+page,
              type:'get',
              dataType:'json',
              async : true,
            }).done(function(results){
              if(results.length > 0){
                objects = objects.concat(results);
                return getObjects(page + 1);
              }
              console.log("Finished",objects);
              resolve(objects);
            }).fail(reject);
          });
        };

        var page = 0;
        getObjects(page).then(function(objects) {
          console.log("getObjects completed",objects);
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Put simply, `getObjects(page)` will be called repeatedly until all the objects are retrieved.

The first `console.log()` shows what I expect, but the `then` function at the end doesn't run.

Interestingly, when I intentionally make the function fail, the `catch` part works properly. Clearly, `resolve` isn't working, but I don't see why.

Any advice will be appreciated.

EDIT

I've tried `reject` and `reject(objects)`, neither worked.

Comment: `resolve;` doesn’t do anything. You mean at least `resolve();`. But of course you want to resolve with some value, so instead of `return getObjects(page + 1);`, try `resolve(getObjects(page + 1));` and remove the `resolve;` down below.

Comment: `$.ajax` already returns a promise. What do you want to wrap it for?

Comment: @Hiroki, now try replacing the `return` statement with `resolve`, as I asked you to in my first comment.

Comment: @Tomalak It returns a regular object for me, not a JavaScript `Promise`.

Comment: @Xufox it may not be a "real" `Promise` object, but the object that's returned adheres to the Promise API - it's "then-able".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Ajax requests are promises. They may not be `Promise` instances, but they implement the Promise interface. There is no need to wrap them.

```
function getObjects(page, objects) {
  page = page || 0;
  objects = objects || [];

  return $.get(url, {pageNumber: page}).then(function (results) {
    objects.push.apply(objects, results);
    return results.length ? getObjects(page + 1, objects) : objects;
  });
}

getObjects().done(function (objects) {
  console.log("getObjects completed",objects);
}).fail(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Also, in this case there is no reason to use the more wordy `$.ajax()`. `$.get()` will do just fine. jQuery will automatically detect a JSON reponse, and Ajax requests are async anyway, so setting the `dataType` and `async` parameters is redundant.

Comment: Tomalak, thank you so much. I even didn't know that `.ajax` itself is a promise. For future googlers, I would say that the result should be parsed into an array, as it turned out that the result was `sting` by default (the result needs something like `JSON.parse(results)`)

Comment: That is only necessary when the server does not send the correct `Content-Type` header.